# Fixed Footer, order of buttons

Tags: google-apps-script, calendar

I have a little bit confused with the google-calendar addon today.
I noticed that secondary and primary buttons have swapped.
The primary button has been on the right side and the secondary on the right, but now they swapped.

Was: [image]

Actual: [image]

I really don't know what happened, it looks like the apps-script team pushed some change to an addon or something like that.

This is my code how I appending the fixed-footer

The service

```js
export class FooterService {
  public static getCardFooter(
    primaryButton: CardButtonInterface,
    secondaryButton? : CardButtonInterface
  ): FixedFooter {

    const footer = CardService.newFixedFooter()
      .setPrimaryButton(ButtonService.getTextButton(primaryButton));

    if (secondaryButton) {
      footer.setSecondaryButton(
        ButtonService.getTextButton(secondaryButton)
      );
    }

    return footer;
  }
}
```

Impleentation:

```js
cardBuilder.appendFooter(
  FooterService.getCardFooter({
    text: buttonBack,
    functionName: NavigationsHandlersNames.goBack,
    backgroundColor: themeConstant.grey
  }, {
    text: selectSite.buttonApply,
    buttonStyle: CardService.TextButtonStyle.TEXT,
    backgroundColor: themeConstant.primary,
    functionName: 'applySelectedChanges'
  })
);
```

Thanks for any help!

Comment: Is `ButtonService` your own code? Also, what's the relation between "back" and "apply", and "delete" and "save"?

Comment: Yes, ButtonService is my own code. There is no relation, the screenshots and code snippets are just for example.

Comment: Instead of pasting all your code, could you create the minimal code possible that we can use?

Comment: see [Minimal Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)